# Why is my .htaccess not working properly?

Tags: regex, .htaccess

so, i was trying to make an API but i encountered a problem with my .htaccess, using this as my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^park/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /park/?r=$1&v=$2 [L]
```

And using for example http://devrosemberg.com/park/profile/DevRo_ i get this strange error:

[image: 404]

I have no idea what to do. Help is appreciated.

Comment: Seems to match it actually - I just escaped some slashes there https://regex101.com/r/cQ2dM3/1

Comment: @Brad His regex seems OK to me!

Comment: What is it that can be wrong then?

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?park/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$   /park/?r=$1&v=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Two things: 1- Did you put this in an `.htaccess` file in root of your server? 2- Do you have access to rewrite log?

Comment: This is running in a website hosting so i cant edit anything, i did place the file where it's supposed to be placed.

Comment: I'm confused! Where did you put the file? document root or park directory?